# How to file a bug against Salesforce Apex?

Tags: apex

[Apex Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/execute.php) reports compile error on the code

`double d = null;
 system.debug(d instanceof double);`

COMPILE ERROR: Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of Double is always an instance of Double

This is clearly wrong, because null is not an instance of double:

`object d = null;
 system.debug(d instanceof double);`

19:32:24.3 (4343472)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|false

Where can I file a bug report?

Comment: Primitives are nullable in apex, so I'm not sure this is a bug. `double d = null;` will compile.

Comment: `double d = null` compiles. `d instanceof double` does not.

Comment: Right, because Double can be `null` or `double`. It's always true. `if (1.23 instanceof Double) { }` will fail during compilation for the same reason.

Comment: not right, because as I showed, `(d instanceof double)==false' if d==null.

Answer (score 1):

When we use Primitive data type we always know what type we declared, either we create a variable or we pass to any function (in both scenario).
So salesforce is not allowing you to check for what you have **manually** declared, You can only check when data type is assigned **dynamically**, Below example will clear the thought :

```
decimal doubleVariable = 0;
Object obj = doubleVariable;
system.debug(obj instanceof decimal);
String stringVariable = 'teststring';
obj = stringVariable;
system.debug(obj instanceof decimal);
system.debug(obj instanceof string);
```

Output :

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question. I asked how to file a bug, not the reason why salesforce issues a compiler bug, as I consider that reson to be wrong.

Comment: I think, Lalit Kishor tried to describe you that it's not a bug :)